# Comparing referenced internal struct field to string type in go

Tags: pointers, go, struct, types, reference

Say I have two structs that define a linked list:

```
....
....

type node struct {
    item interface{}
    next *node
}

type LinkedList struct {
    first *node
    N int
}

...
...
```

and I want to compare the value of the type of the underlying node, say, in a find function where we check if `k == node.item` such that:

```
func (l *LinkedList) find (key interface{}) bool {

    result := false
    if !l.isEmpty() {
        for x:= l.first; x != nil; x = x.next {
            if x.item == key {
                result = true 
                break
            }
        }
    return result
}
```

this will not work for the expected find function because the underlying types are different, hence the func will always return false. We can confirm this upon reflecting the type:

```
fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(key), reflect.TypeOf(x.item)) 
>>> string, *main.node
```

**Tried workarounds?**

I've tried asserting the type but alas this does not work and panics

```golang
tmp := x.item.(string)
>>>panic: interface conversion: interface {} is *main.node, not string
```

This case is the same for using `fmt.Sprintf(x.item)`

I'm a bit stumped as to where to go from here. Is there a way to do this?

**Inserting item to linked list**
The following snippet should clarify how insertion is handled

```
func (l *LinkedList) insertFirst(item interface{}) {
    var first *node = new(node)
    oldfirst := l.first
    first.item = item
    first.next = oldfirst
    l.first = first
    l.N++
}

.....
//which gets called somewhere like
var n *node = new(node)
n.item = item
l.insertFirst(n)


.....wait no theres the error! 
----------
```

burak-serdar you are 100% correct that I am inserting the node in the node!

Comment: If you put a string to node.item, the comparison in find() will work. Looks like you put another node into node.item.

Comment: I am assigning a string to that field node.item. `var n *node = new(node) 
n.item = item
l.insertFirst(n)`. I'll update above with some snippets

Comment: Evidence suggests your insertion function isn't doing what you think and assigning a node to where a string should be.

Comment: you're completely right. I overlooked inserting the node twice. Thanks!

Comment: @BurakSerdar if you want to answer in the form of a response feel free so I can close out this question and mark as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interface comparison in `find()` is a valid comparison and it will work if the type of the key and the type of the value stored in the node are the same. However, evidence points to you adding a node in place of a value.